# Moving router and modem

Tags: router, modem

I am moving from the main house, to an apartment on the same property. The modem and router are currently in the main house but I need to move them to the apartment. The apartment has phone and cable/ coax running into it. In order for me to take the modem and router from the house, and plug it in down at the apartment, do I need anything special done?

Do I need to call my cable provider and have them come make the line in the apartment the "main" line? I hope someone understands what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cable line going to the apartment is directly connected to the one going to the main house (typically using a splitter), you should be able to move your modem and router together to the apartment.

If the apartment is on a separate line from the cable company, you will need their assistance to move the modem and router.  In either case, I would simply try it and see if it works.

Comment: The apartment is officially empty as of today. So checking won't be an issue. I'll give it a go. If it doesn't work, the cable company has to send someone to pick up the old equipment here in a few weeks. I'll just ask them to do what they have to do while they are here. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: My pleasure.  If it's been helpful, please accept and upvote.  Thanks.

Comment: @skyler wood, I wouldn't, make an apt for them to check. Most of the time it's third party contractors picking up equipment. If there isn't a work order, they don't get paid... You probably won't receive a great reaction from the tech. Even if they are in-house technicians they will most likely deny the request in person, missing windowed apts can get you written up when working for these companies.

Answer (score 0):

To make it the "main" line, check where the line comes into the property. Cable modems are supposed to be installed with an "unbalanced splitter".

This just means that if you have a three-way, (or more) one of the outputs will have a lower DB rating typically labeled -3.5 DB. This is the output the cable modem needs to be on. 
[image: unbalanced splitter]

Sometimes they install a two-way splitter off of the main feed, one side feeding the cable modem, and the other going to an additional splitter for set-top boxes.

If you need cable TV and internet in the new home. You may need to buy an amplifier to boost the signal for both coming off of the unbalanced splitter tap.

Regards,